# Using ModelBuilder to tabulate area of overlapping buffer zones in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, merge, error-001156

I'm looking into how much open and close canopy falls within given buffer zones. My buffer zones are a polygon layer created from point sites, but canopy data is a raster with 2 types of data, open or closed canopy. It was pulled from PASDA and has a fairly fine resolution, which is why some other solutions (Converting to polygon) did not work.

This is my first time using ModelBuilder, but I'm attempting to use the tabulate area tool in ModelBuilder by iterating through each row of my buffer zones, tabulating area, and then collecting the new tables. Finally, I use a second model (With the iterating model as a sub-model) to merge these tables together into one output (Added images of models).

However, I'm getting error 001156 (Attached screen shot of error) at the end.

Does anyone have a suggestion to get around this?

It suggests that the string length of columns is limited (This doesn't seem to be the case), or that there is data of one type being written to a column that contains a separate data type. All of the columns from Tabulate area are the same, however.

Unfortunately, I cannot include a screenshot of my tables as they contain locality information for sensitive species. The tables from Tabulate Area have 4 columns (Object ID, Name, Closed Canopy, Open Canopy)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h8u7.jpg

Comment: The error starts at the second row. Is there a way to adjust the amount of allowed characters after using Tabulate area, but before merge?

Comment: Why are you iterating your input features? If you have a selection buffer will work with only the selected features; give each of your input features a unique ID (not FID or OBJECTID) it will be maintained in the buffer polygons, run the tabulate value with Zone Field as the unique ID for each input then your tabulated areas will contain the ID of the input feature. Though if you have overlapping buffers I can see why iteration is necessary.. but create your output feature class first and add nice long string fields then use append instead of merge to bring the data together.

Comment: Yes, it's due to the overlapping buffers. Each site has a unique name, and this is what I'm using to group by in the tabulate area tool. The string length for the Name column is 254, so I'm unsure why it's throwing this error as none of the names are anymore near that high. I'll try running using append instead.

Comment: I created a new, empty table with the same column names as the output from Tabulate Area. It would not populate the table with append.I then renamed one of the tables created from Tabulate Area (As these should be the same columns), and tried once again. It's returning the same error that the merge tool threw.

Comment: That's odd, are there any unicode characters in that row?

Comment: I'm not sure what those are, but with quick googling I don't believe so. The Name column is a name and number- something like "Christmas 1", and the other two columns are "Value_0" and "Value_1", based on the value names of the raster where 0 is open canopy and 1 is open canopy. These two columns are just counts of that value type within the buffer zone pulled from Tabulate Area.

Comment: What happens if you unselect the polygon that is causing a problem?

Comment: All of the polygons are one shapefile

Comment: I've went back through my tables. The Name column in the original table has a string length of 254. However, after the Tabulate Area tool runs, the Name column in the new tables' max length is set to the length of the name of that row. The first one is length of 7 while the second is length of 8. This explains why error 001156 shows up on row two. Does anyone know how to stop it from changing the length of each new column?

Comment: Make sure the values in the field you are iterating over (your Value field) do not have spaces. If they are being used to build the field names in the output of tabulate area then it will be trying to generate invalid field names which the merge tool will fail on.

Comment: Ah, that very well could be it. I'll remove spaces from it and try in a minute. This county only has 8 sites, so it'll be easy to do manually. However, some of these counties have hundreds of sites. Is there a tool that will find spaces and replace them in ArcMap?

Comment: Unfortunately, removing spaces did not stop the error from returning with merge.

Comment: So I've figured out the problem.. In the field map, when I go to run the merge tool, it's setting the field length to 0. If I change the length to any other number, it still errors out. BUT, if I change it again after the error, it works fine. Does anyone know why this is the case or what I can do to stop this and prevent from having to run each tool twice?

Comment: IE: When I set up the merge tool, it's only population the field map with "Name", field length of 0. I changed this to 100 and ran the model. It returned error 001156. Now, the field map is populated with the column names (Name, Value_0, Value_1). I can now set the length of name to 100, and the model runs fine.